# Using Kotlin data class to group path variables in a Spring @RequestMapping annotated method

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, data-class

Currently I am trying to reduce the number of parameters on @RequestMapping annotated methods in a class annotation with @RestController using kotlin data classes. Also I don't want to repeat myself on multiple @RequestMapping annotated methods which contain the same path variables.

The code below shows my approach where `/multiple/ABC/true/123` works as expected but `/single/ABC/true/123` complains about a missing default constructor.

```
data class Params(@PathVariable("param1") val param1: String,
                  @PathVariable("param2") val param2: Boolean,
                  @PathVariable("param3") val param3: Int)

@RestController
class TestController {
   @RequestMapping("/single/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")
   fun single(params: Params) {
       println(listOf(params.param1, params.param2, params.param3))
   }

   @RequestMapping("/multiple/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")
   fun multiple(@PathVariable("param1") param1: String,
                @PathVariable("param2") param2: Boolean,
                @PathVariable("param3") param3: Int) {
       println(listOf(param1, param2, param3))
   }
}
```

When I use the following data class definition instead I get a result but then the instance isn't immutable anymore and may have some fields not updated.

```
data class Params(@PathVariable("param1") var param1: String = "",
                  @PathVariable("param2") var param2: Boolean = false,
                  @PathVariable("param3") var param3: Int = 0)
```

Can anyone help me making the first data class definition work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do that since Spring won't invoke constructors apart from the default constructor.

Another problem is that you can only bind individual path variables to objects so you can't create a complex object this way.

I'd stick with the version which uses `var`s since it works properly and create an immutable object after you receive the request.

Another option is to pass a json object as a parameter because Jackson has more thorough support for this kind of deserialization or you can write a deserializer by hand.

Comment: That's the answer I was afraid of. Maybe I'll try to implement a custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver which does what I want.

Comment: I wouldn't sweat it. Think about it this way: Spring (or Dropwizard, or whatever) is just a framework and it should not have an effect on how you implement your business logic. Just map the data you receive from the REST endpoint to your domain object which can be immutable. More on the topic here: http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html